# Populate dict and json with pandas dataframe data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, parsing

I need help populating a json with a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   vacantes = pd.DataFrame([{'reg': 'Apodaca',
      'puesto': 'Agente telefónico',
      'info': 'izzi estamos buscando personas con vocación en el #Servicio al #Cliente que pueda ayudarnos a brindarle una excelente experiencia a nuestros usuarios, como Ejecutivo Telefónico. ¿Tienes el bachillerato trunco o concluido, facilidad de palabra y resuelves problemas con facilidad? ¡Aplica ahora a nuestras vacantes, envía un inbox o inicia tu proceso en la siguiente liga ,
      'imagen': 'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/5a3001522e0ca8a2e89cb8a15867f25d/96dbae57/130195739_816649878896716_1369158596607266717_o.png',
      'distancia': 0},
     {'reg': 'Apodaca',
      'puesto': 'Ejecutivo telemarketing',
      'info': 'Inizzia a trabajar con nosotros en Apodaca. Buscamos personas que sepan negociar, atender clientes, busqué oportunidades constantemente, demuestren habilidades de negociación y facilidad de palabra.Si cuentas con el bachillerato trunco o terminado y eres mayor de edad, inicia tu proceso en esta url',
      'imagen': 'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/67e9dfb4181719a1a767b8ac3ad33359/0f02d51d/izzi2.png',
      'distancia': 0}])
```

The output that i need looks like this:

```
payload = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements": elements
        }
    }
}
```

Where the elements are filled like this with the pandas dataframe:

```
elements= [
                {
                    "title": ,
                    "image_url": ,
                    "subtitle": ,
                    "buttons": [
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

I need title to be the vacantes['puesto'] column, subtitle, the vacantes['info'] column and image_url the vacantes['image'] column. So for this example i need 2 items in the elements list. Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
# Use list() to get column values
elements = [
    {
        "title": list(vacantes["puesto"]),
        "image_url": list(vacantes["imagen"]),
        "subtitle": list(vacantes["info"]),
        "buttons": [],
    }
]

# Build payload
payload = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements": elements
        }
    }
}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(payload)
# Outputs
# {'attachment': {'payload': {'elements': [{'buttons': [],
#                                         'image_url':['https://dl.airtable.com/..._o.png',
#                                         'https://dl.airtable.com/.../zzi2.png'],
#                                         'subtitle': ['izzi estamos buscando '
#                                                      'personas con vocación '
#                                                      'en el #Servicio al ' ...],
#                                         'title': ['Agente telefónico',
#                                                   'Ejecutivo '
#                                                   'telemarketing']}],
#                           'template_type': 'generic'},
#               'type': 'template'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont quite get the expected values, for example: "title": list(vacantes["puesto"]) gets me title": ['Agente telefónico', 'Ejecutivo telemarketing']  and what i need is to repeat the whole dict in elements for every value in vacantes

Comment: If  ['Agente telefónico', 'Ejecutivo telemarketing'] is split in the main dictionary, what will be the key name for each element, knowing that they can't be duplicated? Adding to your post an example of the full expected result would be useful in order to properly help you.